# The score is not updating. Can you please tell me what is wrong with the code?

Tags: javascript, auto-update

The score is not updating. Please help me make the score update.
When I click the button with the function for 'addScore', the displayed score will not change to a new one.

I have tried a lot of things. Non of which have worked

---

```js
var score = 0;

function addScore(){ score ++ }

function drawScore() { 
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 ctx.font = "16px Arial";
 ctx.fillStyle = "red";
 ctx.fillText("Score: " +score, 8, 20);
}

drawScore();
```

---

I am expecting it to update the score, but it does not. It remains at 0.

The problem has been solved bu the text keeps increasing and over laps it.

Comment: Use the `Element.onclick = function(){ addScore(); }` JavaScript way, making sure that your score variable is above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML elements are not reactive to variables changes. When you created the element with drawScore you informed the current `score` value and inserted this into DOM, however, updating `score` will not update this because it is not a reference.

To make this work you will need to updated `ctx` text on every click.
One simple example would be:

```js
var score = 0;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function addScore(){
 score++;
 setScore();
}

function drawScore() { 
 ctx.font = "16px Arial";
 ctx.fillStyle = "red";
 setScore();
}

function setScore() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
 ctx.fillText("Score: " +score, 8, 20); 
}

drawScore();
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept answer if this is the case.

Comment: But when the code is run the numbers start to over lap each other. Do you have any way to fix this.

Comment: You can clean the canvas before inserting the new value, add `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);` before `ctx.fillText`. I'll edit my answer to insert this.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas does not maintain a reference to your variable (or any values for that matter). Canvas is like an image, it does not have a DOM. You will need to call drawScore() again and maybe clear that portion of the canvas before drawing.

```
function addScore(){
    score++;
    drawScore();
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qfc2hr06/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different coding approach, keeping your CSS, and JavaScript separate from your HTML.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, M, I, S, Q, score = 0, addScore, drawScore; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){ // make yourself a tiny library
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
addScore = function(){
  return ++score;
}
var canvas = I('canvas'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), add = I('add');
ctx.font = '16px Arial'; ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
drawScore = function(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 160, 90); ctx.fillText('Score: '+score, 8, 20);
}
add.onclick = function(){
  addScore(); drawScore();// other functions or code here
};
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px;
}
#canvas{
  background:#fff;
}
#add{
  display:block; padding:3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <canvas id='canvas' width='160' height='90'></canvas>
    <input id='add' type='button' value='add score' />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```